# CSS Navigation: Highlighting

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

Good morning,

I have been playing around with a pure CSS navigation drop-down menu and have come across a problem and was wondering if anyone could help.

I want the page that I am on to stay highlighted in white text with a green background like it does when you hover over it, I also want MENU 1 and MENU 2 to stay highlighted with white text when I hover over their sub-menus. I also am having massive trouble putting the bar into the center of the page or just a div container, I have tried other suggestions and can't get it to center.

Many thanks

Comment: So as per you menu works correct, you just want it at 'CENTER' right?

Comment: I tried center align but it moved all of the sub-menu text to the center as well, however the width needed to be changed for the <li> tags :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code.

```css
#menu
{
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menu ul
{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu ul a
{
    display:block;
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 15px;
    font-family:arial, verdana, sans-serif;
}

#menu ul a:hover
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

#menu ul a:active
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}


#menu ul li
{
    position:relative;
    /*float:left;*/
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

#menu ul li.current-menu-item
{
    background:#70B51E;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.current-MENU,
#menu ul li:hover
{
    background:#70B51E;
    color:#ffffff;
}


#menu ul li:hover > a,
.current-MENU > a{
color: #fff !important;
}


#menu ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0
}

#menu ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    width:200px
}

#menu ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    border-top: 4px solid #70B51E;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #70B51E;
    border-right: 4px solid #70B51E;
    border-left: 4px solid #70B51E;
    background:#70B51E;
    padding:10px 15px
}

#menu ul ul a:active
{
    line-height:120%;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background:#70B51E;
    padding:10px 15px
}

#menu ul ul a:hover
{
    line-height:120%;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background:#3F96A9;
    padding:10px 15px
}

#menu ul ul ul
{
    top:0;
    left:100%
}

#menu ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
<ul>
  <li class="current-MENU -item"><a href="#">MENU </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">MENU 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">SUB-MENU 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SUB-MENU 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SUB-MENU 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  <li><a href="#">MENU 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">SUB-MENU 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SUB-MENU 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">MENU 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">MENU 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason I can't get the page you are on the stay in white text. It's the following extract;

  <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>

#menu ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#70B51E;
 color: #FFFFFF !important;

it just doesn't work.

Comment: I believe, you have used different class name in html and css. Make sure the class name is same in html and css. In your code, you have used the class name "current-MENU" whereas in the css the styles are given to  the class "current-menu-item". Please have a check and let me know

Comment: Thanks well spotted. Although I have changed it now and it will change the background color but it still will not change the font color to white.

Comment: Try replacing #menu ul li:hover > a,
.current-MENU > a{
color: #fff !important;
} with #menu ul li:hover > a, #menu ul li:hover > a:link,#menu ul li:hover > a:active, #menu ul li:hover > a:visited, #menu ul li:hover > a:hover,
.current-MENU > a, .current-MENU > a:link, .current-MENU > a:active, .current-MENU > a:visited, .current-MENU > a:hover{
color: #fff !important;
}

Comment: If that works for you, mark my answer as solution to the question:)

Comment: Hi Som, 

You're a life saver. Many thanks.

I did mark both answers up but it says I haven't got enough reputation for them to display publicly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    add in css 
    #menu ul li.-item
    {
        background:#70B51E;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    #menu ul li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

And also check this link
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ishimdar/catwoahe/)